# How do I add/review remote MySQL access hosts with terminal

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I have a client with a Linux box with no cPanel, I'm not 100% familiar with Terminal and so where I know how to add a 'Remote MySQL access host' through cPanel and see a list of previously added hosts, I have no idea where to access that information directly through terminal... any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add MySQL user using `mysql` command line tool. MySQL user account is consist of 'user'@'host' field.
You can add a user account which can be accessed only from specific remote IPs.

Comment: Sorry, deleted that last comment, was for a different question! LOL (Fail!). Does what you describe correlate directly to the way cPanel handles remote MySQL access hosts? In cPanel there's no association with a user, just a general list of allowed IPs.